# Non-interactive tar_visnetwork()/tar_glimpse()?

Tags: r, targets-r-package

Background: I work in terminal R on a remote system and don't have interactive graphical capabilities. Perhaps I could manage to get X11 working but so far I have been productive using some workarounds, rendering plots to file directly and mounting the remote image dir using sshfs.

Interactive graphics don't work for me but I'd like to visualize target dependencies. Is it possible to somehow render `tar_visnetwork()` to a static image? Something like the following (which doesn't work)?:

```
png('test.png')
tar_visnetwork()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar_visnetwork` creates a HTML widget. You can render this file in your local Browser:

```
library(targets)
library(htmltools)

save_html(html = tar_visnetwork(), file = "dag.html")
```

Comment: `webshot::webshot(tar_visnetwork())` can print it. I'm also working on mermaid.js graphs: https://github.com/ropensci/targets/issues/775

Comment: Awesome, `webshot` doesn't work for me but `save_html` does :)